# Camel and load balancer

Tags: apache-camel

I am using camel to implement a route, that load data from DB and then apply some processing on it before producing results that are saved in the DB again.
This is part of a web application.

My problem is this war is going to be deployed by a load balancer into two servers. Then there will be two camel contexts with two routes performing the same processing on the same DB.

I will have the case where the same record is being processed by the two routes. How to handle this problem to prevent the routes from performing the same job twice?

Comment: Is the load balancer not sending the request to only one of the 2 servers? And if so, only one of the servers is processing the record? If not can you explain better why you have 2 CamelContext processing the same record at the same time?

Comment: Also this question is not really Camel specific, but more a general architectual problem

Comment: The routes are configured to run periodically using "timer". So they are both running on the two servers.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have that setup so that each server might receive the same record - then you need an [idempotent route](http://camel.apache.org/idempotent-consumer.html). And you need to make sure your idempotent repository is the same between your machines. Using a database as the repository is an easy option. If you do not have a database, a hazelcast repo might be an option.

What can be an issue is to determine what is unique in your records - such as an order number or customer + date/time or some increasing transaction ID number.